# response from uWsgi lost

Tags: mysql, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a django app hosted via Nginx and uWsgi and remote Mysql DB. In a certain very simple request:
Im randomly getting 502 with below error in uwsgi.log Sometimes it works, sometimes not... I couldn't find any reason to justify when not works...  Can anybody help me to understand whats going on and how to resolve it?

```
*** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 1 (pid: 26789, try: 1) ***
HARAKIRI: -- wchan> 0
*** backtrace of 26789 ***
uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x29) [0x451c09]
uwsgi(what_i_am_doing+0x19) [0x452069]
/lib64/libc.so.6 [0x399da302d0]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(read+0x4b) [0x399e20daab]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15(vio_read+0x38) [0x2b03e853ab98]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15(vio_read_buff+0x43) [0x2b03e853abf3]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15 [0x2b03e853bdf8]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15(my_net_read+0x199) [0x2b03e853c1f9]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15(cli_safe_read+0x6f) [0x2b03e8535d5f]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15 [0x2b03e8536bc9]
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15(mysql_real_query+0x1e) [0x2b03e853553e]
/array/purato/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so [0x2b03e82d27e9]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6185) [0x2b03e18e36b5]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x679a) [0x2b03e18e3cca]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x679a) [0x2b03e18e3cca]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x679a) [0x2b03e18e3cca]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x56b3) [0x2b03e18e2be3]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x679a) [0x2b03e18e3cca]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e187359c]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xddd) [0x2b03e18de30d]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e187359c]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xddd) [0x2b03e18de30d]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x679a) [0x2b03e18e3cca]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e187349d]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e1857f9f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e18a2f4a]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x1127) [0x2b03e18de657]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8cf) [0x2b03e18e4c7f]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 [0x2b03e187349d]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b03e1848548]
/array/purato/python/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x56) [0x2b03e18dc906]
uwsgi(python_call+0x20) [0x45f240]
uwsgi(uwsgi_request_wsgi+0x11c) [0x4619ec]
uwsgi(wsgi_req_recv+0x8f) [0x41ef7f]
uwsgi(simple_loop_run+0xc5) [0x44d3c5]
uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x132) [0x44ffc2]
uwsgi(uwsgi_worker_run+0x252) [0x450262]
uwsgi(uwsgi_start+0x13ad) [0x45169d]
uwsgi(main+0x1be6) [0x454f36]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x399da1d9c4]
uwsgi [0x419fe9]
*** end of backtrace ***
HARAKIRI: --- uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 26789) WAS managing request /brizer/ since Tue Oct 13 12:01:51 2014 ---
*** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 1 (pid: 26789, try: 2) ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 26789) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 27845)
```

Anybody knows something about that?

Answer (score 0):

You are Harakiri enable in uwsgi. Try without Harakiri.

Comment: Harakiri is a part of uwsgi. What im feeling is my worker thread is stuck somewhere due to which this error is coming. Im not sure where.

Comment: I think that could be the problem Harakiri or uwsgi config file. What is your configuration file?

Comment: processes = 4

log-x-forwarded-for

master

vacuum = true

chmod-socket = 666

max-requests = 5000

post-buffering = 4096

listen = 4000

harakiri = 10

harakiri-verbose = true

buffer-size = 10000

Answer (score 0):

You have a mysql query requiring more than 10 seconds to generate the response. After 10 seconds the harakiri is triggered destroying your process. You can obviously increase or remove the harakiri but it will only mitigate a serious performance problem. You should fix the query generated by /v2/cost/. If you have difficults identyfing it, enable the mysql slow_query log